# Getting record in reverse order from pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Usually we get data from the parent relation table and we get the record of the pivot and its relational table in the laravel but can we get the record using pivot table in eloquent?

Like I want to get the products record from the pivot table with its quantity record which is making it unique so I want to get the products data from the pivot table. Can we do that in laravel ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the built in query building functions to  generate the table data in reverse order to do that.
**e.g.**

$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

will return you a array which is ordered in the reverse relevant to user id. 
further you can use many more functionalities. Please read the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: Sorry Use the latest Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am trying to get data in reverse relation order. Like getting parent data  using pivot table record. e.g. Getting product information from the pivot table ids. Can we do that in laravel ?

Comment: So you can add a column to your pivot table indicating the production id of the certain row. I think now what you need is some knowledge about database relations. Given below is an example how to create such a relationship between Item Order and ordered_Items tables.

Answer (score 0):

In this example think as a customer orders a item from our store. Then you should be able to track the items in the order, Customer details, quantity and etc. So we can do this by using the following classes.

- Customer
- Order
- Order_item
- Item

So first we have to mention the database relationships in the model. e.g. a customer have many orders. So in Customer model indicate it as a function as follows.

public function order(){

```
           return $this->hasMany(App\Order);
```

}

Also in the Order Model

public function  customer(){

```
       return $this->belongsTo(App\Customer);
```

}

When crating the migration file you should leave unsigned intiger column for customer_id in the orders table. When saving the data you should save the relevant customer_id in the order details. **e.g.**
orders table will look like follows.

- id(unsigned, aoutoincrement, integer)
- customer_id(unsigned, integer)
- total_price
- etc
  And keep in mind that to save the auto increment id in the customer table to orders table customer_id. Or let laravel do this for you by using the handy method or like,

$order->customer_id=$customer->id //assuming that you have the customer object crated above.
However i prefer to save the id manually since its more clear for me.

So when ever you want to find the customer of the certain order look back in the customer table with the customer id. **e.g.**

$customer=Customer::where('id',$order->customer_id)->first();

If you want to find the orders of a particular Customer you can do it like ,

$orders_array= Order::where('customer_id', $customer->id)-get();

So you can traverse both sides easily. I didn't get what you meant by pivot table. Is that Pivot tables in Excel would like to help if you could describe more.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Really appreciate that. :)

But actually I was talking about laravel pivot table which we usually use for many to many relationships. And we actually dont make the model of that table in the laravel which I am assuming is not traditional way to do. May be we can but i didnt see anywhere or in any example where we make model of the pivot table.

Comment: More about pivot table  here:
http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Now in laravel we can easily get the records from the pivot table using its parent relation/model. But we cant easily get record directly from the pivot table. Thats what I want to do. I think i should make a model and try with that. 

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry For being unable to help.